# Producer - consumers in C++ using Boost library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to design and implement a program that is going to "solve" the classic producer-consumer problem. I'll also be using the publish/subscribe pattern and there's only one producer.

The first thing that came to my mind was to implement each thing as a separate thread, but then I realized that this is inefficient and there probably are smarter ways to do it.

I need to:

- accept tcp/ip connections from clients
- get the data using a named pipe from another process (named pipe can change to anything else here)
- as soon as I get the data decide which clients should get it and send it there
- be able to parse client commands at any time (eg. client wants to change the subscription details)
- also depending on implementation details I might want to clear the collection that holds incoming data(if only I need to have one) and kick inactive clients

My idea now is:

- create a thread that is going to accept connections from the clients and add each client to a list
- create a thread/pool of threads that are going to execute a strand(`boost::strand`) that is going to consist of reading the data from the source, deciding which client should get data and asynchronously writing the data to the clients.

I do not know if

- this is valid approach
- this is efficient approach
- how to add reading commands from the client(s) ?
- how to check client inactivity

I would be grateful for any comments and proposals on how to properly implement something like this.

Comment: I feel that this question, while well-posed, well-formatted and reasonably well-structured, is a tad too open-ended for SO.

Comment: Any suggests on how to improve it? Maybe move it to some other StackExchange site?

Comment: I suggest a chatroom or mailing list of some variety, where you can engage in a _discussion_. You're not going to get a one-shot answer that satisfies you.

Comment: I've found that this question is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com so I'm going to move it there.

Comment: Please don't. I already said, it's a request for a discussion, not a question with an answer.

Comment: agree with @Lightness, move this to the chat room

Comment: This is not suited for a chat room. Look at how big the question is. I don't expect discussion here. The difference between this question and a usual SO question is that here more answers can be equally valid. I don't like the thing that there's extended discussion on the validity of a question rather than at least a single answer! The question is precise - I want an implementation proposal for well defined and known design patterns.